# Epub in Windows Phone App 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a mobile app in windows phone 8.1.  I need to open an epub book and tried this code, it does not work.

How can i initialize it like this

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Inetpub\ePubReader\temp\load tests\");

        Console.WriteLine("Started");

        foreach (var file in files) {
            try {
                Epub epub = new Epub(file);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("FileName: " + file + ", Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work in window phone. Which library should I use or what exactly should I do? I want to know the process of viewing the epub book in window app ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library:

[Epub Reader](https://epubreader.codeplex.com/)

This works for C# 4.0 and above, and it may work on Windows Phone too. It gives some examples on how to implement it.

To import it into your project, follow these steps:
1- unzip the downloaded package from the mentioned site;
2- the zip file contains two DLLs. I recommend you to put these in a directory inside your project. You don't need to include this directory in the solution on Visual Studio.
3- Right-click on your project and click on **References** option. A panel with libraries to be imported will be shown. 
4- Go to **Browse** and select the two DLLs unzipped.

After you do this, the example code should work when you build the project.